# How can I bind my route to a stepper in angular-material2?

Tags: angular, angular-material2

I'm using the [Stepper component](https://material.angular.io/components/stepper/api) of angular-material2 and I want the steps to be reflected in the URL route of my application, so that the users can share the URL links and get immediately to a proper step. Is it possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to inject and use Location service from `'@angular/common'`:

1) To change the URL call go function of Location service. Example:

```
if (this.stepper.selected.label === 'subscriber') { 
    this.location.go('./enrollment/subscriberInfo');
}
```

2) To change the stepper after URL change call subscriber function of Location service. Example:

```
this.location.subscribe( () => {
    if (this.location.isCurrentPathEqualTo('/enrollment/subscriberInfo')) {
        this.stepper.selectedIndex = 0;
    }
    if (this.location.isCurrentPathEqualTo('/enrollment/payment')) {
        this.stepper.selectedIndex = 1;
    } 
    if (this.location.isCurrentPathEqualTo('/enrollment/agreement')) {
        this.stepper.selectedIndex = 2;
    }
});`
```

FYI, I used `@Output() animationDone: EventEmitter<void>` of stepper to change URL.